# Is it possible to execute client-side commands from the server-side during an ssh connection?

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to send command from server ssh to client. Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

**NO**!

If what you are looking for would be possible, it would definitely be a huge security issue.
For clarity, let us assume that your client is named A and server is named B.
if you have ssh server running on A, and you have public keys from B added to your client A, (or through any other auth mechanism) you will have to create a new connection from B to A to make changes to it.